# What is the best way to point to an array from a class in an array that gets overwritten during copying?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a debug menu system to make debugging easier, and am using arrays of custom classes for menus, and the actual options do work, but links to submenus, which I'm trying to implement as links to other arrays, don't (they give me a null reference exception).

The only way that somewhat worked was by manually defining each submenu in each option that points to a submenu, but that is clunky and unorganised,
and I have also tried to use Array.Clone() but that also causes a null reference exception.

```
public static debugoption[] MainMenu = new debugoption[2]
    {

        new debugoption {
            OptionTitle = "Jump to Scene",
            IsSubmenuNotOption = false,
            CurrentOptionValueFunction = GetSceneSelection,
            SubmenuToGoTo = null,
            CallFunction = SelectScene,
            HasEnterFunction = true,
            EnterFunction = LaunchScene
        },

        new debugoption {
            OptionTitle = "Front End ->",
            IsSubmenuNotOption = true,
            CurrentOptionValueFunction = null,
            SubmenuToGoTo = FrontEnd,// debugmenu.FrontEnd.Clone() as debugoption[],
            CallFunction = null,
            HasEnterFunction = false,
            EnterFunction = null
        }
    };
```

I expect it to change the array that I use to store the current menu, but none of this, apart from that clunky method, work.

Comment: You need to post the code that does not work rather than the code that does. Your question mentions copying but there is no copying going on here.

Comment: I posted how I define it, as the code that copies it is just an Array.Copy(), which is safer than setting the arrays directly